# Perform JOIN on multiple tables with acceptable NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have multiple tables and trying to perform `JOIN` query.
The following code works okay, except when one of the columns in WHERE clause is NULL - I don't get any results at all.

Do I need to use FULL OUTER JOIN?

Please help.

```
SELECT  tickets.*,

    tickets_statuses.name AS statusname,

    tickets_priorities.name AS priorityname,

    clients.name AS clientname,

    clients_locations.name AS clientlocationname,
    clients_locations.address AS clientlocationaddress,
    clients_locations.address2 AS clientlocationaddress2,
    clients_locations.city AS clientlocationcity,
    clients_locations.state AS clientlocationstate,
    clients_locations.zip AS clientlocationzip,
    clients_locations.country AS clientlocationcountry,

    clients_contacts.prefix AS clientcontactprefix,
    clients_contacts.firstname AS clientcontactfirstname,
    clients_contacts.middlename AS clientcontactmiddlename,
    clients_contacts.lastname AS clientcontactlastname,
    clients_contacts.title AS clientcontacttitle

FROM    tickets, tickets_statuses, tickets_priorities, clients, clients_locations, clients_contacts
WHERE   tickets.id = '$ticket_id'
    AND tickets_statuses.id = tickets.statusid
    AND tickets_priorities.id = tickets.priorityid
    AND clients.id = tickets.clientid
    AND clients_locations.id = tickets.clientlocationid
    AND clients_contacts.id = tickets.clientcontactid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first, I'd say you want to get rid of the old syntax of `JOIN` and use standard `JOIN ... ON` syntax.

The query may look like this, though the order and joining may vary depending on what columns you want.  Below assumes you always want an item in `ticket` and any of the others may or may not exist:

```
SELECT  tickets.*,
        tickets_statuses.name AS statusname,
        tickets_priorities.name AS priorityname,
        clients.name AS clientname,
        clients_locations.name AS clientlocationname,
        clients_locations.address AS clientlocationaddress,
        clients_locations.address2 AS clientlocationaddress2,
        clients_locations.city AS clientlocationcity,
        clients_locations.state AS clientlocationstate,
        clients_locations.zip AS clientlocationzip,
        clients_locations.country AS clientlocationcountry,
        clients_contacts.prefix AS clientcontactprefix,
        clients_contacts.firstname AS clientcontactfirstname,
        clients_contacts.middlename AS clientcontactmiddlename,
        clients_contacts.lastname AS clientcontactlastname,
        clients_contacts.title AS clientcontacttitle
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN tickets_statuses
    ON tickets.statusid = tickets_statuses.id
LEFT JOIN tickets_priorities
    ON tickets.priorityid = tickets_priorities.id
LEFT JOIN clients
    ON tickets.clientid = clients.id
LEFT JOIN clients_locations
    ON tickets.clientlocationid = clients_locations.id
LEFT JOIN clients_contacts
    ON tickets.clientcontactid = clients_contacts.id
WHERE tickets.id = '$ticket_id'
```

Comment: `JOIN ... ON` syntax makes sense! Thanks.